# Word - Add a bookmark between existing bookmarks or at end of document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, bookmarks

I have an application where I need to be able to insert a ContentControl after the end of the current bookmark.  In other words when the user clicks a button on the toolbar, the app should identify what bookmark (if any) contains the application.selection.range.start move to the end of the bookmark, insert a ContentControl and bookmark the new control.

It seems no matter what I try, the new content control is inserted into the existing bookmark -or- if I set the range.start to range.end+1 I receive an out of bounds exception.

As you consider this, bear in mind that there may be bookmarks.count == 0 or the bookmark may be at the very end of the document so bmk.range.end +1 is past the end of the document.

Thanks in advance,
Eddie